# Возможно ли использовать конструктор new ResizeSensor более чем с одним элементом?

Tags: javascript

Есть два блока, необходимо их сравнивать и в зависимости от ширины и высоты совершать определенные манипуляции.

Нашел [такую библиотеку JS](http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/), в том числе поддерживающую Jquery (хотя на Jquery иногда и неверно вычисляющую размеры), но на JS вычисляет всегда правильно. Вот [репозиторий на github](https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries).

Собственно вопрос. Возможно ли изменить следующую функцию (конструктор) чтобы работать в ней сразу с двумя (как минимум) или более селекторами?

**Вот так работает только с одним.**

```
var element1 = document.querySelector(".div-resize1");
var element2 = document.querySelector(".div-resize2");

new ResizeSensor(element1, function(size){
    console.log('Ширина: ' + size.width + 'px');
    console.log('Высота: ' + size.height + 'px');
    console.log('размер содержимого изменен');
});
```

Необходимо чтобы работало с **element1** и **element2** **одновременно**.

Заранее, благодарю!

Comment: Передавайте их массивом

Comment: @Alexander Chernin Как потом разделить, например, значения высоты у element1 и element2

Comment: По индексу элемента в массиве. Изучите работу с массивами

Comment: @Alexander Chernin - думаешь не пробовал... `console.log(size.height[0]);` выдает в консоли **двжды undefined** так как `size.height` не является массивом: `console.log(Array.isArray(size.height));` выдает **false**, а является переменной с типом **number**

Comment: А size откуда берется?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin - хватит намеков (я далеко не програмист) напиши пожалуйста как вывести по отдельности, если знаешь. Уже по разному пробовал, ничего не получается.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100333/discussion-between-ozoro-and-alexander-chernin).

Comment: а по какому событию-событиям, происходят изменения размеров, за которыми Вы следите?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q - onload и onresize

Comment: предлагаю по этим событиям сравнивать значения размеров, зачем Вам библиотека?

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку данная библиотека не передает в колбеке информацию о элементе, который меняется, придется немного костыльно написать.

В данном примере, когда дивы будут равны, вы увидите два сообщения:

- The second is bigger
- They are equal

Это происходит потому что, два события не могут происходить одновременно. Сначала срабатывает событие изменения первого (становится меньше), затем второго (становится меньше) элементов.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item-for-resize-tracking');
var itemSizes = {};

// Setup ResizeSensor on target item
items.forEach(item => {
  new ResizeSensor(item, function(e) {
    itemSizes[item.id] = e;

    compareSizes();
  });
});


function compareSizes() {
  const size1 = itemSizes['item-1'];
  const size2 = itemSizes['item-2'];
  if (size1 && size2) {
    if (size1.width === size2.width) {
      console.log('They are equal');
    } else if (size1.width > size2.width) {
      console.log('The first is bigger');
    } else {
      console.log('The second is bigger');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#item-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#item-2 {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/marcj/css-element-queries/master/src/ResizeSensor.js">
</script>


<div class="container">
  <div id="item-1" class="item-for-resize-tracking">
    <span>Hello world!</span>
  </div>
  <div id="item-2" class="item-for-resize-tracking">
    <span>Hello world! 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

В данном примере мы "синхронизируем" события, функция `compareSizes` будет вызвана только тогда, когда все элементы изменят свой размер.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item-for-resize-tracking');
const itemSizes = {};
const sizeChanges = {};

// Setup ResizeSensor on target item
items.forEach(item => {
  sizeChanges[item.id] = false;
  new ResizeSensor(item, function(e) {
    itemSizes[item.id] = e;
    sizeChanges[item.id] = true;
    if (!Object.values(sizeChanges).some(a => !a)) {
      compareSizes();
      Object.keys(sizeChanges).forEach(f => sizeChanges[f] = false);
    }
  });
});


function compareSizes() {
  const size1 = itemSizes['item-1'];
  const size2 = itemSizes['item-2'];
  if (size1 && size2) {
    if (size1.width === size2.width) {
      console.log('They are equal');
    } else if (size1.width > size2.width) {
      console.log('The first is bigger');
    } else {
      console.log('The second is bigger');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#item-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#item-2 {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/marcj/css-element-queries/master/src/ResizeSensor.js">
</script>


<div class="container">
  <div id="item-1" class="item-for-resize-tracking">
    <span>Hello world!</span>
  </div>
  <div id="item-2" class="item-for-resize-tracking">
    <span>Hello world! 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: благодарю, буду пробовать.

Comment: единственное. у меня задача сравнивать ВЫСОТУ блоков у которых `display:inline-block; width:50%` и если один блок становится больше (при разных разрешениях) на величину, например 100px, то делать `display:block; width:100%` добавляя класс. При этом списки ul li в первом блоке (верхнем) должны распределяться на 2 колонки. Если блоки при определенном разрешении становяться высотой с допустимым значением, то удалять класс `display:block; width:100%` и в первом блоке списки делать в одну колонку.

Comment: кроме того, какими способами ни пробовал это делать, всегда получается, что при ресайзе высота определяется верно, а вот при load (если перезагрузить страницу) в том случае когда блоки с классом `display:block; width:100%` и в первом блоке списки в две колонки высоту постоянно определяет неверно. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @ozoro Проблема в том, что вы не верно задали вопрос. Ваш вопрос был **Возможно ли использовать конструктор new ResizeSensor более чем с одним элементом?**. А теперь появляются какие-то колонки, загрузка, различное разрешения экрана. Хорошо заданный вопрос - это половина ответа! Для различных разрешений хорошо подходят `media queries`.

Comment: `media queries` не подайдет. Я же написал о зависимости НЕ ОТ РАЗРЕШЕНИЯ, а ОТ ВЫСОТЫ БЛОКОВ, а это в свою очередь зависит от контента в этих блоках. При различных разрешениях высота блоков меняется и если разница в высоте больше, например, на 100 px, то выполнять манипуляции с блоками.

Comment: Извините, чьи комментарий выше, в которых говорится - *единственное. у меня задача сравнивать ВЫСОТУ блоков у которых display:inline-block; width:50% и если один блок становится больше (**при разных разрешениях**) ...* и *При **различных разрешениях** высота блоков меняется ...*. Какое понятие вы вкладываете в слово **разрешение**?

Comment: высота блоков изменяется когда меняется ширина браузера, может не точно выразился, написал разрешение, думал понятно будет. В любом случае благодарю за помощь, показал принцип как сделать.

Comment: Опять же, если у вас конкретная проблема - вы про не вопрос и задавайте. В комментариях вы пишите про ошибочное определение высоты блоков, при различных условиях, а в вопросе у вас про **Возможно ли использовать конструктор new ResizeSensor более чем с одним элементом**. Лучше задайте новый вопрос. P.S. Разрешение (экрана) и размер браузера - разные вещи.

Comment: Задал новый вопрос, прошу помочь. **Заранее, благодарю!** https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042395/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F